# Unterminating while loop in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store values in double array in a while loop with a terminating value of -1. It seems the values are being stored fine but when -1 is entered the loop does not terminate. Any ideas? Thank you so much!
[screen shot of the problem area](http://gyazo.com/28f73794f6e53a92a160f147e5ed87e0)

```
int main(void)
{
    double a[7],dev[6],mean, std;
    int i,n;
    int entered;
    char letg[6];

    cout<<"Please enter the test grades one at a time (max 6)\n";
    cout<<"enter a -1 when you are done entering scores\n";
    //based off class notes
    i=0;
    cin>>entered;

        while (entered>0)
      { a[i]=entered;

        i++;
        cin>>entered;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please post the code in this answer instead of as an image on another page?

Comment: Add your code to your question.  Screen snapshots may be difficult for others to read depending on the resolution of their screens and yours.

Comment: Instead of posting a screen shot post the text in the question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Use curly braces after your `while` loop to show which statements are inside the loop and which are not.  That should help.

Comment: I indented your program using conventional indentation techniques.  now the problem should be obvious.  you are not looping the lines that you think you are.

Comment: You may want to look at the `{` before the while(), it will fit better after.

Comment: Indenting code consistently can often help identify problems. Use your editor's automatic formatting facilities to ensure code is always indented correctly.

Comment: { placed after while and probelm is still occuring, i'm currently getting a core dump.

Comment: You should check the bounds like while (entered > 0 && i < 7).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
{while (entered>0)
```

to

```
while (entered>0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your process is executing the `statement a[i]=entered;` indefinitely. You should put the braces after the while loop:

```
while (entered>0)
{
    a[i]=entered;
    i++;
    cin>>entered;
}
```